# lxml tree.xpath() scraping product description of single product from flipkart results in scraping of all product's description

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, lxml

I tried creating a nested list for product description of each of the products using lxml method xpath in Flipkart

```
    product_descriptions = []
    for des in tree.xpath('//ul[@class="_1xgFaf"]'):
      description=[]
      for i in des.xpath('//li[@class="rgWa7D"]/text()'):
        description.append(i)
      product_descriptions.append(description)

    for i in product_descriptions:
      print(i)
```

But it results in obtaining all the li[@class="rgWa7D"] in the page instead of obtaining all the <li> elements of one <ul> element.

Comment: FYI “scrapping” means throwing things away like rubbish - the term you want is __scraping__

Comment: @barny That’s a typo mate. Anyway, Thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting your XPath with `/` means the context is the root document, that's why your 2nd XPath returned all `li` elements with class "rgWa7D" in the page. If you want the context to be the current `ul` element, as referenced by variable `des`, add `.` to the beginning of the XPath:

```
for i in des.xpath('.//li[@class="rgWa7D"]/text()'):
    description.append(i)
```

Comment: @NikhilVijay No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved the problem in question